# ListSelectionListener causes View to freeze - only if external LookAndFeel is activated

Tags: java, swing, freeze, java-11, listselectionlistener

I have quite a specific problem with *Swing* on *OpenJDK 11* and im curious if someone have an idea to help with this. Im using *Swing* in my software and in one of my dialogs the program is freezing for a while every second or third click on a *JTable*. The changes caused by that are beeing processed in a ListSelectionListener starting like this:

```
 getSelectionModel()
    .addListSelectionListener(
        e -> {
          if (!e.getValueIsAdjusting()) {
          ...
```

This happens only when using *OpenJDK 11*. I'm also using an external LookAndFeel where i dont have access to the source code. If im disabling the LookAndFeel everything works fine as well - even with *OpenJDK 11*. But also the View works fine, if i comment a part of my code. The most interresting part is - wherever i do a system time output in the listener to find the problem there is no bigger delay. Even if i use my code which seems to be able to cause delay. The delay is always happening before. So my guess is that the LookAndFeel maybe overwrites some swing internals which struggles with processing the Events. Does anyone here has an idea which function or part of swing could cause that behaviour?

On Java 8 everything used to work fine. I'd appreciate every clue to solve that.

Comment: Is your custom L&F adopted to Java 11? The problem is, that lots of internal Java API was made unavailable on migration from Java 8 to Java 9. So some L&F, that worked fine on Java 8, can work incorrectly in Java 9 and higher.

Comment: officially it should work on java 11